# Article Usage in Standard American English

Tags: american-english, articles

Here is the text:

> "This is a 29-year-old Arn Anderson, who looks much older than that. It seems the stress of keeping the crowds entertained every night got to him and aged him much quicker than the average person."

According to the rules, in the last phrase, it should be "*an* average person" because the meaning is *any* average person. Why did they use *the*?

Comment: This applies to the average person. [everyone]//This applies to an average person. [any average person]

Comment: @Lambie as pointed out in the suggested duplicate - please vote!